# repository for python3-devel on CentOS 7?

Tags: centos7

What repo is ok to use to install python3-devel on CentOS 7 ?

I seem to find only Fedora and OpenSuse versions.

```
yum install python3-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.coreix.net
 * epel: ftp.lysator.liu.se
 * extras: mirrors.coreix.net
 * updates: mirrors.coreix.net
No package python3-devel available.
```

Comment: CentOS 7 did not ship with Python 3 in the repositories. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @MichaelHampton it looks like OP is trying to run Python 3 on CentOS 7.

Answer (score 15):

You can always activate the [EPEL Repository](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL), it has a [python34-devel package](https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/repoview/python34-devel.html) available.

Comment: Philipp: welcome to SF.  Concise, informative, well-referenced answer - +1 from me, I hope you stay around and keep it up.

Comment: Is the EPEL repository activated by default when installed? I have it installed, but still do not find a python 3 devel package...

Comment: I can't comment on the first answer, so I add an answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43047284/how-to-install-python3-devel-on-red-hat-7
provides a way to find and install the package.
find packages: `yum search python3 | grep devel`,
choose a package (e.g., python3-devel.x86_64),
and install the package: `yum install -y python3-devel.x86_64`